# Binding NodaTime Instant field in an InputModel body using C# ASP.NET WebAPI 2.0

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding, nodatime

I have an WebAPI project that takes in ISO date strings inside the input model. I have been parsing these using `DateTimeOffset?`. I want to banish BCL datetimes from my project so I want to find a way to directly bind these strings to `Instant`.

```
public class MyInputModel
{
    public DateTimeOffset? OldTime { get; set; }

    public Instant NewTime { get; set; }
}
```

An example JSON input model looks like this:

```
{
    "oldtime":"2016-01-01T12:00:00Z",
    "newtime":"2016-01-01T12:00:00Z"
}
```

And my controller code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostTimesAsync([FromBody]MyInputModel input)
{
    Instant myOldTime = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(input.oldTime.Value.UtcDateTime);
    Instant myNewTime = input.newTime; // This cannot be used with ISO date strings.
}
```

I attempted to build a custom model binder as follows. **This works for models in the query string but not for those in the body of a POST request. How can I bind date input in an ISO 8601 string format to a NodaTime Instant?**

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bindingContext.ModelName) && 
            bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Instant?) && 
            bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName) != null)
    {
        Instant? value;
        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider
.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).FirstValue as string;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        else if (InstantExtensions.TryParse(val, out value))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(value);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, 
"The date is invalid.");
        }
    }

    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

public static bool TryParse(string value, out Instant? result)
{
    result = null;

    // If this is date-only, add Utc Midnight to the value.
    if (value.Length.Equals(10))
    {
        value += "T00:00:00Z";
    }

    // Trim milliseconds if present
    var decimalPointIndex = value.IndexOf('.');
    if (decimalPointIndex > 0)
    {
        value = value.Substring(0, decimalPointIndex) + "Z";
    }

    // Attempt to parse
    var parseResult = InstantPattern.GeneralPattern.Parse(value);
    if (parseResult.Success)
    {
        result = parseResult.Value;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: For what `Type` you registered your model binder?

Comment: Hi Aram, I haven't registered it - in the query strings I use it as follows:  

`[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(InstantModelBinder))]Instant? time = null)`

Comment: Try adding this `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Instant?), new InstantModelBinder());` in `Global.asax.cs`

Or maybe without question mark as I see in `MyInputModel` it isn't nullable.

Comment: I should have mentioned - this is a dotnet ASP.NET WebApi 2.0 project. We are not using a Global.asax.cs file.

Comment: Add it in `Startup.cs` file. In `Configuration` function like this:
`public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Instant?), new InstantModelBinder());
    ...
}`

Comment: I added it. It says "The name ModelBinders does not exist in the current context." Where can I get the ModelBinders object from?

Comment: Sorry, I forget it was for `MVC`, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your model binder like this: ( in `WebApiConfig` `Register` method )

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.BindParameter(typeof(Instant), new InstantModelBinder())
        ...
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.Register is called in `Configuration` function in `Startup.cs` file. In most cases like this:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(config);
```

If it isn't called, you can just add this line:

`config.BindParameter(typeof(Instant), new InstantModelBinder())`

where `HttpConfiguration` object is being created in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: Sorry - I still don't know where this is supposed to go. Is this method called by the startup class?

Comment: Yes you should have this in your startup class, or maybe similar thing, you just need `HttpConfiguration object` to call `BindParameter`.

Comment: I have a `Configure` method, but no references to `HttpConfiguration` and if I try `var config = new HttpConfiguration();` I can't find the namespace for it - it's a big project yet we don't have the relevant packages installed; I feel like this is the wrong approach?

Comment: If no `HttpConfiguration` is created, how your web api is registered?

Comment: Can I see your `Startup.cs` file.